# Flutter - How to Rebuild the SiverList without also rebuilding the SliverAppBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

If I can't use a FutureBuilder inside a CustomScrollView how I can rebuild only the SliverList without also rebuilding the SliverAppBar?

I'm doing an app similar to Youtube, so like Youtube I have several buttons with the categories inside a ListView in the SliverAppBar area (Example in the image below) and a SliverList with the videos, but currently everything inside the CustomScrollView is rebuilt when I click on a category button. And the ListView inside the SliverAppBar always goes back to position 0 after rebuilding it instead of staying in the same position like Youtube.

[image]

The ideal result would be just rebuilding the SliverList. Or at least keep the ListView position (on the SliverAppBar) in the same position that was before rebuilding. How that can be done?